# How to prevent exposing client secret when using laravel passport?

Tags: laravel, api, access-token, laravel-passport

I'm trying to implement laravel's passport to protect my api routes and I have a case where the route should be inaccessible unless it is called by an authorized application. I am trying to use [Client Credentials Grant Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens) and using postman I am able to generate an access token, which then I can use for access authorization.

The problem is - I don't understand how should I safely use this with `Vue` and `axios`. I have my component in which I need to call this api, I can of course set a form body including all the necessary fields (`client_id`, `client_secret` and `grant_type`) but that would mean that anyone could just open up chrome dev tools and search for `client_secret` in the source and they would get the hardcoded client secret, which would grant them access to the api. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you use your Vue frontend.

If it is a frontend mostly for your own site, but sometimes needs to access an external API, than you should have your backend make the API calls and store secrets there.

If you are developing a Vue frontend dedicated to the external API, but running on a different domain, you could go for the PKCE option: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#code-grant-pkce

If you have a frontend on the same domain as the API, use the CreateFreshApiToken option provided by Laravel passport.

Comment: Yup, CreateFreshApiToken sounds like the perfect solution, since it is the same webpage, not an external api. I've followed the steps provided in documentation (actually just the one step that is provided) but it doesn't seem to work, from what I understand it should work straight up after I add it to the middlewares but I do get a 401 response. Also this seems like it would affect all of my routes but in fact, I want some of them to require authentication. How can I apply this middleware only to some routes?

Comment: I don't quite understand how this should work though, does this still mean there needs to be an authenticated user logged in? Because all I want to achieve is for this route to be available for consuming from Vue but off limits from outside

Comment: Misread the question will look through it and see if it can be adjusted :)